# Date values from an int and a string in separate columns

Tags: date, tableau-api

I have an issue where I'm trying to get a date value out of 2 columns. One has int values in the '2017" format and the other has 'April' as the 2nd. How can I combine them to create a "2017-04-0000" date?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use the dateparse formula. That way you can combine your separate fields and create a new datestamp.

Create the calculated field as follows, note here I have made the day the 1st of the month you could change this to suite your purpose:

```
dateparse('ddMMMMyyyy', '01'+[Manufacture Month]+str([Manufactured year]))
```

Find out more [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_typeconversion.html#dateparse)